# how can I attach multiple pre-existing AWS managed roles to a policy?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, terraform

I want to associate existing policies in AWS to a role, I am using the terraform tool

I want to associate these policies, this code is with the aws cloudformation tool:

```
   AWSCodeCommitFullAccess
   AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess
   AWSCodeDeployFullAccess
   AWSCodePipelineFullAccess
   AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess
```

try with the attach

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "attach-policy" {
  arn = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeCommitFullAccess", "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess", "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeDeployFullAccess", "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodePipelineFullAccess"]
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "tc-role-policy-attach" {
  role = "${aws_iam_role.toolchain-role.name}"

  policy_arn = "${data.aws_iam_policy.attach-policy.arn}"
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any code either in Terraform or CloudFormation?

Comment: try with the attach

data "aws_iam_policy" "attach-policy" {
  arn = [
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeCommitFullAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeDeployFullAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodePipelineFullAccess"
  ]
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "tc-role-policy-attach" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.toolchain-role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${data.aws_iam_policy.attach-policy.arn}"
}

Comment: You should edit your question to include the code you've written so far. You can also format it into a code block once you've done that to make it easier to read.

Comment: This results in error as : │ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
Inappropriate value for attribute "arn": string required. When I passed list of arns in data "aws_iam_policy" "attach_policy" . Any idea , how can I resolve ?

Answer (score 9):

You go with the right direction with terraform resource [aws_iam_role_policy_attachment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/iam_role_policy_attachment.html) but need some adjustment.

AWS managed policies' [ARN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) are exist in the system. For example, if you need attach the first managed policy to an IAM role,

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "test-policy-AWSCodeCommitFullAccess" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeCommitFullAccess"
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.toolchain-role.name}"
}
```

You can add other managed policies one by one.

If you want to do together, you can try below code

```
variable "managed_policies" {
  default = ["arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeCommitFullAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeBuildAdminAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeDeployFullAccess",
    "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodePipelineFullAccess",
  ]
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "tc-role-policy-attach" {
  count      = "${length(var.managed_policies)}"
  policy_arn = "${element(var.managed_policies, count.index)}"
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.toolchain-role.name}"
}
```

Comment: The `list[index]` syntax is preferable to using `element()` whenever you don't need to loop back through the list with an index higher than the length of the list.